# Django test module produce these errors

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am very new at Django. I am following the tutorial by Vitor Freitas, "A Complete Beginner's Guide to Django". In the test module, I get the error shown below.  Can some kind sole guide me as to my error.

```
ERROR: test_redirection (boards.tests.test_view_reply_topic.SuccessfulReplyTopicTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/Desktop/PythonProjects/myproject/myproject/boards/tests/test_view_reply_topic.py", line 34, in test_redirection
    self.assertRedirects(self.response, topic_posts_url)
AttributeError: 'SuccessfulReplyTopicTests' object has no attribute 'response'
```

The file it is referring to is this file

```
class SuccessfulReplyTopicTests(ReplyTopicTestCase):

    def test_redirection(self):
        url = reverse('topic_posts', kwargs={'pk': self.board.pk, 'topic_pk': self.topic.pk})
        topic_posts_url = '{url}?page=1#2'.format(url=url)
        self.assertRedirects(self.response, topic_posts_url)
```

=====================================================

```
FAIL: test_redirection (accounts.tests.test_view_signup.SuccessfulSignUpTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/Desktop/PythonProjects/myproject/myproject/accounts/tests/test_view_signup.py", line 62, in test_redirection
    self.assertRedirects(self.response, self.home_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 348, in assertRedirects
    % (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: 200 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```

The file it is referring to is this file

```
class SuccessfulSignUpTests(TestCase):

   def test_redirection(self):
         self.assertRedirects(self.response,self.home_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code here : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/09/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-6.html

1 - Do you have this part written correct ?

```
class LoginRequiredPostUpdateViewTests(PostUpdateViewTestCase):
    def test_redirection(self):
        '''
        Test if only logged in users can edit the posts
        '''
        login_url = reverse('login')
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '{login_url}?next={url}'.format(login_url=login_url, url=self.url))
```

2- Obviously the code has many errors, and there is comments about it on the post, have you checked them all ?

3- Have you checked the code in github ? 
Best of luck!

Comment: I have double checked the codes very carefully.  Also checked against github.  I could have missed something.  Will check again.  Thanks for trying

Comment: You are absolutely right aymanezizi.  I left a bunch of codes out by  my carelessness.  Now it works ok.  Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help :)